# clang++: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

**clang++: command not found**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.4 LTS
- clang --version: 10.0.0

clang++ work outside of this program. But when I run this program show this error message *clang++ command not found*

````
PATH=/home/musleh/programming/cpp
DIR=''
FILE=''

execute () {
    cd ${PATH}/${DIR}
    clang++ ${FILE} -o a 
    time ./a
    rm a

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "***************************Program Fail***************************"
    fi
}

while getopts i:d: OPTION 
do
    case ${OPTION} in
        d)
            DIR=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        i)
            FILE=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        ?)
            usage 
            ;;
    esac
done

if [[ $# -lt 4 ]]
then
    usage
elif [[ ! -d ${PATH}/${DIR} ]]
then
    echo "${DIR} dir not found!" >&2
elif [[ ! -f ${PATH}/${DIR}/${FILE} ]]
then
    echo "${FILE} file not found!" >&2
else
    execute
fi```
````

Comment: Run the command `apt-get install clang++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> PATH=/home/musleh/programming/cpp
> ```

Is very probably wrong and should be instead perhaps

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/programming/cpp
export PATH
```

Read much more more about the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and [execvp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) (which most shells use)

Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your shell script. Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and more about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and read its documentation. It is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) so your are allowed to study (and perhaps improve) its source code.

Of course, `clang++` needs to be installed. Check by using the `which`  command. Or view your `PATH` variable using `echo $PATH`

See also [this](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/10319/910)

Comment: I rename the PATH variable and it's working thanks for helping